# Csharp Windows phone task complete

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I'm making Windows universal app using Visual Studio 2013.  I'm trying to accomplish something like in [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/gg521153%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).
On the main page I have many pictures.  After clicking on one of these pictures the user goes to another page, which has a check box.
After user checkes the check box, I have to change the image on main page.

I don't know if this code is correct, but I'm doing something like this for second page

```
private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    points.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(points.Text) + 4).ToString();

    var currentCheckBoxItem = sender as CheckBox;
    if (currentCheckBoxItem.IsChecked == true)
    {
      otra.bedre1.Source = (new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/complete.png", UriKind.Absolute));
//     }
```

But this is code for mainpage where can choose task:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    bedre1.Source = ImageSource;

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I have try use something like this:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/gg521153%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

but i had one problem, i have two page, in one page is Task to choose and another page can see active task.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to store the name and Checkstatus as fields inside SQlite database so that its available even after the app is closed. So you would need to do some research on it.

Comment: Did you think something like this?
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/55275a/windows-phone-8-1-sqlite-how-to-store-data-in-database/

Comment: Well thats right you will be able to show different tasks as your task list will keep on incresing and you can then use a flag or some value as completed pending etc to check out your status of task and update your UI accordingly. Its not a small task and will result you in getting familiar with Database Query, Binding in UI etc.

Comment: That great idea:)
Hope its work:))
Anyway thanks alot:)
If it work , I'will say:)